# Criar um Script PHP puxando dados do Excel

Tags: php

Bem quero uma ajuda quando a criar um script em PHP puxando 2 dados numa tabela de excel, o arquivo é xlsx, eu teria que puxar dados em colunas diferentes, alguém pode me ajudar em como fazer isso???

Answer (score 0):

Para esta situação, eu utilizo a classe [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). [Aqui tem um tutorial em português](https://blog.adlerdias.eti.br/como-ler-aquivos-do-excel-com-php/) explicando como fazer a utilização dessa classe. Mas basicamente, você precisa informar o caminho até o arquivo, definir a aba que está ativa e transformar todos os dados em um array para que você possa manipular os dados. A sua pergunta já foi respondida também, no [Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398765/how-do-i-use-phpexcel-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file).

Answer (score -1):

Divirta-se!

[As 30 classes top de PHP para Excel](https://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/30-classes-top-de-php-para-excel/?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Uma dessas classes com certeza irá lhe auxiliar.